# Randomly split a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of size `46928x28x28` and I want to randomly split that array into two sub-matrices with sizes `(41928x28x28)` and `(5000x28x28)`. Therefore, to randomly pick rows from the initial array. The code I tried so far (to calculate the indexes for the two sub-arrays) is the following:

```
ind = np.random.randint(input_matrix.shape[0], size=(5000,))
rest = np.array([i for i in range(0,input_matrix.shape[0]) if i not in ind])
rest = np.array(rest)
```

However, surprisingly the shapes of ind is `(5000,)` while the shape of the rest is `(42192,)`. What am I doing wrong in that case?

Comment: Wouldn't `train_test_split` from `sklearn` work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is that `randint` is giving some repeated indices. You can test it by printing `len(set(ind))` and you will see it is smaller than 5000.

To use the same idea, simply replace the first line with

```
ind = np.random.choice(range(input_matrix.shape[0]), size=(5000,), replace=False)
```

---

That being said, the second line of your code is pretty slow because of the iteration over the list. It would be much faster to define the indices you want with a vector of booleans, which would allow you to use the negation operator `~`.

```
choice = np.random.choice(range(matrix.shape[0]), size=(5000,), replace=False)    
ind = np.zeros(matrix.shape[0], dtype=bool)
ind[choice] = True
rest = ~ind
```

On my machine, this method is exactly as fast as implementing scikit.learn's `train_test_split`, which makes me think that the two are doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

One way may be to try using `train_test_split` from `sklearn` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# creating matrix
input_matrix = np.arange(46928*28*28).reshape((46928,28,28))
print('Input shape: ', input_matrix.shape)
# splitting into two matrices of second matrix by size
second_size = 5000/46928

X1, X2 = train_test_split(input_matrix, test_size=second_size)

print('X1 shape: ', X1.shape)
print('X2 shape: ', X2.shape)
```

Result:

```
Input shape:  (46928, 28, 28)
X1 shape:  (41928, 28, 28)
X2 shape:  (5000, 28, 28)
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the comment that `train_test_split` might be the way to go. However, since this is tagged `numpy`, here is a `numpy` way of doing things, which is pretty fast:

```
# recreate random array:
x = np.random.random((46928,28,28))

# pick your indices for sample 1 and sample 2:
s1 = np.random.choice(range(x.shape[0]), 41928, replace=False)
s2 = list(set(range(x.shape[0])) - set(s1))

# extract your samples:
sample1 = x[s1, :, :]
sample2 = x[s2, :, :]
```

Your output:

```
>>> sample1.shape
(41928, 28, 28)
>>> sample2.shape
(5000, 28, 28)
```

**Timings:**

Just out of curiosity, I timed this `numpy` method compared to `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` and got little difference. `train_test_split` is faster, but only by a tiny bit. In any case, I stand by `train_test_split` being the better option.

**`numpy` method:** 0.26082248413999876 seconds on average

**`train_test_split` method:** 0.22217219217000092 seconds on average

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick update to say that this is readily solved using `shuffle`:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.shuffle(data, axis = 0)
split1 = data[:41928]
split2 = data[41928:]
```

If you're using this for an ML application, this has the added benefit of randomizing the order of your train and test sets, which is often desirable. If you need to preserve the given ordering on the two split arrays, you can shuffle indices instead and re-sort:

```
idx = np.arange(data.shape[0])
rng.shuffle(idx)
idx1 = np.sort(idx[:41928])
idx2 = np.sort(idx[41928:])
split1 = data[idx1, ...]
split2 = data[idx2, ...]
```